# What does "hampered 10" mean in Pathfinder 2e?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, conditions

When affected by the 2nd stage of a Graveknight's Curse, a creature is:

> doomed 2, hampered 10, and cannot remove the armor

*doomed* is a standard condition, but afaik *hampered* isn't. What does it do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Your Speed is Reduced by 10 Feet

The hampered condition was part of the [playtest for Pathfinder 2e](https://paizo.com/pathfinder/rules/playtest), but wasn't included in the official release. Despite that it did slip into a few places, including the various [graveknight entries](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterFamilies.aspx?ID=291) (mostly just referencing the ability, though it was included in the *Book of the Dead*'s variant).

Here's the description from the playtest:

> **Hampered**
>
> Your Speed is reduced. Hampered is always followed by a
> number indicating by how many feet the condition reduces
> your Speed. This condition can’t reduce your Speed below
> 5 feet. If the condition doesn’t specify which of your
> movement types it applies to, it applies to all of them. You
> can have both the accelerated and hampered conditions at
> the same time, so if you were accelerated 10 and hampered
> 15, your Speed would be reduced by 5 feet.

Comment: I really wish Hampered made it into official play haha. "Their speed is reduced by" every time you slow an enemy down gets really pedantic, especially since you can't use the word 'slowed'